# Elementor custom widget rendering nested widgets

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm looking into Elementor as a potential solution and just trying to understand its capabilites, one thing I want to be able to do is render widgets within widgets, maybe Im approaching this all wrong, but I cannot for the life of me see how this is done.

Say for a very simple example Im trying to create a simple widget that renders bootstraps grid system:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
       // some content
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to create a "Row" widget, that when put onto the page, will allow users to drag a "Col" widget inside of it, then of course add other widgets inside of that for the actual content.

My question is, in their documentation I can't see where you call for the widget to render any child widgets.

I guess im thinking of something like  in vue or yield in rails.

It must be possible since they themselves have a grid system already right?

Any help is appreciated.